# Resource for linear algebra with new angle bracket notation

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question, notation, book-recommendation

In class, we learned the angle bracket notations for vectors in linear algebra, but I am unable to find a textbook that uses the notation.
ex: <"v1 | v2"> (without quotes)

Could you recommend a good textbook that also uses the notation?

Comment: This looks like BraKet notation, which is more commonly used in physics than in mathematics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $\langle a|b\rangle$ to represent the inner product of $a$ and $b$ is very rarely used in mathematics. It's common in quantum mechanics, and will be defined in any introductory textbook. My preference is for **Introduction to Quantum Mechanics** by David Griffiths. If you're looking for a formulation of linear algebra in terms of it, that's going to be harder to find but might exist in a linear-alg-for-physics book